# Swift TVOS - Focus moving between cells but UICollectionView not scrolling

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, focus, tvos, apple-tv

I have a TVOS app which has a UICollectionView with many cells. 
I'm moving between the cells using the remote to move the focus. This works as expected, and the UICollectionView scrolls when I reach a cell that isn't visible.

Occasionally, a problem occurs with the scrolling. 
This has happened when the app comes back from the background, or when the ATV device is disconnected and reconnected to the HDMI cable, or when the ATV device returns from sleep mode.
I cannot consistently reproduce it, it just happens from time to time.

The problem:
Moving between cells with the remote works, the focus moves, until I reach cells that are not visible. Then, I expect them to scroll into visibility, but they don't. 
The focus however allows me to move to the cells that are outside of visibility, and I am also able to come back to the cells that are visible.

Any ideas??

Comment: Rather new to tvOS myself, but this sounds like a possible bug. I'd file a bug report and check with Dev. Support on this one...